# Safari - flex box container width with flex direction column

Tags: javascript, html, css, safari, flexbox

I am seeing an odd behavior with `flex` boxes on Safari when a flex column container is inside another flex row container. When column flex container has  `flex-wrap: wrap` property set, it's width is greater than it's children. This behavior happens only on Safari, Chrome and Firefox it works as expected.

[Codepen with flex wrap which has unexpected width for parent on Safari](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OMobNL)

[Codepen without flex wrap where parent width is as expected](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zrJoNR)

Safari version - 9.0.3

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35137869/3597276

Comment: Please provide us with a complete example (HTML and CSS both) that reproduces the problem you're having.  @Michael_B How is that relevant to this question?

Comment: @Blazemonger, it tells the OP that Safari may require vendor prefixes for flexbox to work property.

Comment: @Blazemonger here you go http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OMobNL , thanks to this now I can rephrase my question better. This happens when this parent is inside another container which has flex direction row. I am updating question as well.

Comment: Also updated description with copepen without wrap which shows width as expected.

Comment: What version of Safari are you using?

Comment: This is on Safari 9.0.3